# ORACLE SQL replacing the substring dynamically in a big string based on another substring

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, replace

I have a table which stores SQL queries in string column like below. 
 (I have given 3 sample rows below)

```
select sql_query_part_1_tx  from Table1;

sql_query_part_1_tx
--------------------------------------------------------
SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCC04<>'US' AND HIRHCE01 IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;
SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND HIRHCC04<>'US' AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND HIFD1516<>'Y' AND HIFD1527='FDIC';
SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND HIRHCC04<>'US' AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND HIFD1516='Y';
```

So the column sql_query_part_1_tx stores SQL queries in string format. my requirement is to read these queries and execute them dynamically and stores the results in another table.

Here the challenge in the above stored queries is wherever there is <> (not equal to) condition, it is not fetching rows with NULL values (which is expected). But I need rows with NULL values also.

For ex :

```
SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCC04<>'US' AND HIRHCE01 IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;
```

In the above query string, there is condition `HIRHCC04<>'US'`. So it will not fetch records with `HIRHCC04 IS NULL`.

I want to change the above query string like below, apply `NVL` function wherever I find `<>` in the condition .

```
SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND NVL(HIRHCC04,'###')<>'US' AND HIRHCE01 IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND NVL(HIREG234,999999) <> 345 ;
```

So that I can get rows with `NULL` values for `'HIRHCC04'` and `'HIREG234'` also.

So I want to update my Table which stores these query strings with `NVL` or `COALESCE` option. I hope I am clear.

NOTE : Please note that we need to consider datatype and "NOT IN" condition.

Comment: This is a bit tricky.  You have both strings and numbers that need to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_query_part_1_tx, '(\w+)\s*<>', 'COALESCE(\1, 9999) <>') 
FROM mytable;
```

Regexp explanation:

- `'(\w+)\s*<>'` captures words (ie consecutive alphanumeric and underscore characters) at the left of the `<>` sign, with an optional sequence of spaces in between
- `'COALESCE(\1, 9999) <>'` : replaces the matched string, with the captured word (column name) referred to as `'\ 1'`

This **[demo on DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1fda04310d98eb8dc00020b64351481f)** with your sample data returns:

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE(SQL_QUERY_PART_1_TX,'(\W+)\S*<>','COALESCE(\1,9999)<>')                                                                                                                              |
| :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND COALESCE(HIRHCC04, 9999)<>'US' AND HIRHCE01 IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND COALESCE(HIREG234, 9999)<> 345 ; |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND COALESCE(HIRHCC04, 9999)<>'US' AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND COALESCE(HIFD1516, 9999)<>'Y' AND HIFD1527='FDIC';                      |
| SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND COALESCE(HIRHCC04, 9999)<>'US' AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND HIFD1516='Y';                                                   |
```

---

Incidently, let me suggest an optimization to your replacement logic.

This:

```
COALESCE(HIRHCC04, 9999)<>'US'
```

Is usually better spelled:

```
(HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US')
```

The second expression is more explicit and more efficient, as it will happily use an existing index on the column being filtered (while the first expression will not). It also avoids potential conversion issues when the column being checked is not a number.

These expressions could be generated with the following regex:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    sql_query_part_1_tx, 
    '(\w+)\s*<>\s*''(\w+)''', 
    '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 <> ''\2'')'
) 
FROM mytable;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b5cc2c58f38d265aa5f93b59f65237b)**:

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE(SQL_QUERY_PART_1_TX,'(\W+)\S*<>\S*''(\W+)''','(\1ISNULLOR\1<>''\2'')')                                                                                                          |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND HIRHCE01 IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;   |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND (HIFD1516 IS NULL OR HIFD1516 <> 'Y') AND HIFD1527='FDIC'; |
| SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND HIFD1516='Y';                                      |
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated query that will also process `NOT IN` clauses, and allow both numbers and strings on the left side of the  `<>` operator (and in `NOT IN` lists):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_query_part_1_tx, '(\w+)\s*<>\s*(''*\w+''*)', '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 <> \2)'), 
    '(\w+)\s*NOT IN\s*(\([^)]+\))', 
    '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 NOT IN \2)'
) FROM mytable;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fed9267332a679861d93f6015d97748e)**;

```
| REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SQL_QUERY_PART_1_TX,'(\W+)\S*<>\S*(''*\W+''*)','(\1ISNULLOR\1<>\2)'),'(\W+)\S*NOTIN\S*(\([^)]+\))','(\1ISNULLOR\1NOTIN\2)')                                                                                    |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1  AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND (HIRHCE01 IS NULL OR HIRHCE01 NOT IN ('TDCD','TDOA','IRATD')) AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND (HIREG234 IS NULL OR HIREG234 <> 345) ; |
| SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND (HIFD1516 IS NULL OR HIFD1516 <> 'Y') AND HIFD1527='FDIC';                                               |
| SELECT SUM(OUTSTANDING_AM) FROM SCH.DEFD1520 WHERE 1=1  AND HIRHCV04='Y' AND (HIRHCC04 IS NULL OR HIRHCC04 <> 'US') AND HIRHCN17='FDIC' AND HIFD1516='Y';                                                                                    |
```

Comment: THANK YOU. can we extend the same for <> occuring more than once ? Unfortunately, I don't know how many times it might occur in the string.  Secondly, can we extend this to NOT IN clause as well ?   For EX : lets take the string below.....    select 'SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1 AND HIRHCC04<>''US'' AND HIRHCE01 NOT IN (''TDCD'',''TDOA'',''IRATD'') AND HIREG039 NOT IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;' as q
     from dual;     Is it possible to split the expression you have used and explain ?

Comment: @Nag: I should have mentionned... `REGEXP_REPLACE()` treats *all* occurences by default, no issue there.

Comment: @Nag: for `NOT IN`, we would have to use another regexp. Try: `REGEXP_REPLACE(
    sql_query_part_1_tx, 
    '(\w+)\s*NOT IN\s*(\([^)]+\))', 
    '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 NOT IN \2)'`. This works in **[this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a71e4f872ee0c2d07d26e1753566540)** (I added a `NOT IN` condition to the first record).

Comment: COALESCE(HIRHCC04, 9999)<>'US'  --> This is giving data type mismatch. So we need to check the right side of <>, whether it is string or number. Anyway, the second option is very good to split  the condition with OR. If we can extend that for multiple occurances of <> and "NOT IN" clause, my problem is solved. I tried hard but breaking one or the other way. Please help.

Comment: @Nag : just run each `UPDATE` query one by one, and you will get the desired output, isn't that ok?

Comment: Or you can nest the `REGEXP`s : `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(sql_query_part_1_tx, '(\w+)\s*<>\s*''(\w+)''', '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 <> ''\2'')'), 
    '(\w+)\s*NOT IN\s*(\([^)]+\))', 
    '(\1 IS NULL OR \1 NOT IN \2)'
) FROM mytable;` **[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14c6573294bf348428a390ab2230b1fc)**

Comment: EXCELLENT !!! THANKS AGAIN.....   just wondering why it is not able to replace the last condition HIREG234 <> 345 in first row ?

Comment: @Nag: because it has no surrouding quotes, while others do... I updated my answer with what should be the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION:

> Here the challenge in the above stored queries is wherever there is <> (not equal to) condition, it is not fetching rows with NULL values (which is expected). But I need rows with NULL values also.

This is really nasty.  I can't say that I really condone this.  Your queries are not written consistently (in one place there are spaces around `<>` and in the other no spaces).  I suspect that there might be a better solution to your overall problem than storing such raw SQL.

That said, I can appreciate that you have a problem.  This is tricky, because you have both strings and numbers, which makes things tricky.  You could have dates.  The following will not work on dates.  But, `regexp_replace()` can do something:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(q, ' ([^ <]+) ?<> ?''', ' NVL(\1, ''XXX'') <> '''), ' ([^ <)]+) ?<> ?[^'']', ' NVL(\1, -1) <> ')
from (select 'SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1 AND HIRHCC04<>''US'' AND HIRHCE01 IN (''TDCD'',''TDOA'',''IRATD'') AND HIREG039 IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;' as q
     from dual) x
```

Note:  This pretty much assumes that the reference before the `<>` is a single column reference, not a more complicated expression.

Comment: Thank you. This covered <>. Can we extend this for 'NOT IN' as well (for both NUMBERS and STRINGS) ? example below     select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(q, ' ([^ <]+) ?<> ?''', ' NVL(\1, ''XXX'') <> '''), ' ([^ <)]+) ?<> ?[^'']', ' NVL(\1, -99) <> ')
from (select 'SELECT SUM(BAL_AM) FROM SCH.DERHCE03 WHERE 1=1 AND HIRHCC04<>''US'' AND HIRHCE01 NOT IN (''TDCD'',''TDOA'',''IRATD'') AND HIREG039 NOT IN ((660),(661),(604)) AND HIREG234 <> 345 ;' as q
     from dual) x